# php for loop increase and decrease value same

Tags: php

php for loop increase and decrease value same 
for decrease value i code this

```
for ($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){
echo $i."<br>";
}
```

its output is

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

but i want this

```
10
1
9
2
8
3
7
4
6
5
5
6
4
7
3
8
2
9
1
10
```

Now i want to know how i can achieve this result

Comment: this is logical issue rather than programming issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it, whole output will be dependent only on value of $i.

```
for($i=10,$j=1;$i>=1;$i--)
{
    echo $i.'<br>';
    echo $j.'<br>';
    $j++;
}
```

Comment: You can move the `$j++`to after the `$i--` `for($i=10,$j=1;$i>=1;$i--, $j++)`

Comment: did and it works , aftab solution is very simple and time saving and Terminus your hint is awesome makes less complicated

Comment: glad to help u @BilalRaj :)

Answer (score 2):

You just need a little bit of math

```
for ($i=10; $i>=1; $i--){
    echo $i."<br>";
    echo 11 - $i."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for($up = 1, $down = 10; $up <= 10; $up++, $down--) {
    echo $down, "\n", $up, "\n";
}
```